# How to migrate ArcGis Online data to external database?

Tags: dojo, arcgis

I am using Arcgis Online. I want to migrate my feature layers (data which stored in esri's internal database) to external database.

Can anyone help me to figure out how I can do it? Also how can I use external database in my Application(PostgreSQL/Neo4j).What I need is, to host my own database server like neo4j and use as a replacement of feature-table provided by ArcGis.

Thanks,
Tarni

Answer (score 0):

You have many options for downloading data from ArcGIS Online.

1. If you do not have many feature services, the easiest way would be to go to "My Content", then find your feature service. You should see an "Export Data" option towards the top-right.
2. If you have multiple feature services, you could repeat the directions above, but choose "Open in ArcGIS Desktop". This will download a file that will set up the connection in ArcMap for you. You can also hit the services directly from ArcGIS Desktop by going to "My Hosted Services" in ArcCatalog and logging in.
3. Another option is to use a Python script. This may be best if you have alot of data, and if the data is updated frequently. Check out https://github.com/tedrick/SyncSurvey for an example of getting data repeatedly from a feature service.

Comment: Thanks for reply Jeremy. But actually what I need is, to host my own database server like neo4j and use as a replacement of feature-table provided by ArcGis.

Comment: I would recommend placing that question in its own post.